# Using ModalController to display extra content in Ionic app

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a page with a list of Pokemons. I want to use a modal to show more info about the pokemon when the user clicks on it. I dont want to make another page just for a description. Is there anyway to use a Modal to display all the description and just close that modal?

Comment: any code base you try? if try then add in the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask in order to improve your question

Comment: I tried it in TypeScript and when I run it and I get the error: Modal's page not defined